# Writing an array to a file in C, File should be in human readable format

Tags: c, arrays, file

Trying to learn C fundamentals. I am writing an array to a file. I am successful in writing the data into the file and reading it back also. However the data is written into the file in the binary form, which is not human - readable. 
How can we write the data into the file so that it will be in human-readable format.

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    typedef struct array
    {
        int n;
        int arr[100];
    } array_t;

    void print_array(array_t e)
    {
        printf("%s\n", __FUNCTION__);
        int i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < e.n; i++)
            printf("%d\n", e.arr[i]);
    }

    int main()
    { 
        FILE *f1;
        array_t e, f;
        int i;

        printf("Enter Array Size:\n");

        scanf("%d",&e.n);

        for(i = 0; i < e.n; i++)
        {
           int temp;
           printf("Enter %dth element\n", i+1);
           scanf("%d",&temp);
           e.arr[i] = temp;
         }

         print_array(e);

         f1 = fopen("one.txt", "wb+");
         int ret = fwrite(e.arr, sizeof(int), e.n, f1);

         fclose(f1);

         f1 = fopen("one.txt", "rb");
         f.n = e.n;

         for(i = 0; i < e.n; i++) {
             int temp = 0;
             fread(&temp, sizeof(int), 1, f1);
             f.arr[i] = temp;
         }

         printf("This is read array\n");
         print_array(f);

         return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Convert integer to string and write string.

Comment: You need a delimiter sign which is not part of your array value domain.

Comment: I believe fwrite is supposed to have the behavior you are complaining about. Take a look at fprintf, it may be what you are looking for. 
(http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/)

Comment: You used `printf` to print in human-readable format to screen, then use `fprintf` to do the same into files.

Comment: ...after opening the file in text mode with `f1 = fopen("one.txt", "wt")`

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be like this:

```
f1 = fopen("one.txt", "w");
```

And all `fread` -> `fscanf` , `fwrite` -> `fprintf`.

Also these operations in the loop (`fprintf`)

Answer (score 0):

`fread` and `fwrite` are binary stream input/output functions. They're not really the correct tool to write formatted data to an output stream.

Take a look at [`fprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/) and [`fscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/). They should be closer to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In this case "human readable" means ASCII, so if you want to have the *characters* 0 to 9 in your file you have to write the *numbers* 0x30 to 0x39 (or the chars '0' to '9')